# Merge Tags doctrine-and-covenants & doctrines-and-covenants

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Can someone with the vote count or a mod merge [doctrine-and-covenant](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-and-covenant) and [doctrines-and-covenants](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrines-and-covenants)?

Also, should those just get deleted all together? We have two perfectly good [doctrine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrine) and [covenant](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covenant) tags...

Comment: I just merged them.  And no, it shouldn't be deleted. "Doctrine and Covenants" is the name of a book that the Latter-Day Saints consider scripture, and as such is a proper noun, distinct from the "doctrine" or "covenant" tags.  Thanks for noticing the duplicate.

Comment: @MasonWheeler ah, wasn't aware of that. cool stuff. thanks.

Comment: How did neither of these tags have the right plural? I can see one right and another typo tag but both wrong?

Comment: @Caleb: Actually, Thomas just mistyped the first tag, which was actually doctrine-and-covenants.  I managed to sort it out with a bit of searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mason already took care of the merge](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/merge-tags-doctrine-and-covenants-doctrines-and-covenants#comment3055_1370), and apparently the rename to [doctrine-and-covenants](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-and-covenants). How both of the previous tags managed to have the wrong plural I have no idea.

I also removed the tag from a couple questions where it seemed to be miss-placed on questions about either doctrine or covenants but not [Doctrine and Covenants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_and_Covenants)

Comment: WRT the mistagged questions, I added a quick docwiki that should make people less likely to make that mistake in the future.