# Can we (how do we) merge the tags "peter" and "peter-apostle"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

My apologies if there is a better way/place to ask this; I didn't see anything and there seems to be [precedent](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/merge-tags-doctrine-and-covenants-doctrines-and-covenants) for requesting this on Meta.

Shouldn't the tag [peter](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/peter/info) be a synonym for [peter-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peter-apostle) for consistency (see paul and paul-apostle)?

Answer (score 3):

It's normal to have separate tags for bible-books and people. In that case I believe the proper tags should be 1-peter 2-peter and peter, with peter-apostle merged into peter. 3 of the 5 questions tagged 'peter' are about the man.

Comment: I changed the two questions about 1-peter to 1-peter, there's no 2-peter questions (which is good because the tag should stick around then) should be OK to synonomize them now

Answer (score 2):

They are not *intended to be* synonyms

Peter is intended to be the book of [peter](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peter) and [peter-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peter-apostle) is intended to be about the man, though that's not at all clear from the tag wikis(and in fact that wiki for Peter indicates it's for the apostle which is not the case).

Comment: Then shouldn't there be tags 1-peter 2-peter and peter-apostle?

Comment: @DJClayworth i agree

Answer (score 1):

I made the changes to the remaining unretagged questions.

[peter-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peter-apostle) now has not questions associated with it.